# pytest rasing error - Fixture "teardown" called directly

Tags: python, pytest

I'm maintaining some suite of tests written in pytest. After upgrade of the pytest to version 7.x I got error like this:

> Fixture "teardown" called directly. Fixtures are not meant to be called directly,
> but are created automatically when test functions request them as parameters.
> See https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/explanation/fixtures.html for more information about fixtures, and
> https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/deprecations.html#calling-fixtures-directly about how to update your code.

This message is clear and I'm fully aware of this change. Still I don't know why pytest raises it in the below scenario:

```
import pytest

class TestDemo():

    @pytest.fixture(scope="class")
    def teardown(self, request):
        def teardown():
            pass
        request.addfinalizer(teardown)

    def test_demo(self, teardown):
        return True
```

Do you have any suggestion where this "direct call" occurs ?

Comment: You may want to give your local function another name than the method/fixture.

Comment: It doesn't help and error is still about the "teardown" fixture. So it seems that even if the local function is passed , the wrapping fixture is somehow "processed" in pytest internals.
Generally I have a "fix" or "workaround" - I want to rather understand what is wrong.

Comment: Actually, this is a strange way to implement it - the usual way would be to call your teardown code directly after the yield. Also, you would usually make that kind of fixture an `autouse` fixture. Though that still does not explain the error...

Answer (score 0):

`teardown()` is actually a [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#module-unittest) style method. It's called automatically after the `test` is finished, but as part of the test case and not as part of normal `pytest` teardown, so `pytest` see it as a `fixture` that is being called directly.

From [unittest.TestCase Support](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/unittest.html#unittest-testcase-support) (notes sections at the bottom of the page)

> unittest.TestCase methods cannot directly receive fixture
> arguments as implementing that is likely to inflict on the ability to
> run general unittest.TestCase test suites.

> Due to architectural differences between the two frameworks, setup and
> teardown for unittest-based tests is performed during the call phase
> of testing instead of in pytest’s standard setup and teardown stages.
> This can be important to understand in some situations, particularly
> when reasoning about errors. For example, if a unittest-based suite
> exhibits errors during setup, pytest will report no errors during its
> setup phase and will instead raise the error during call.

I suggest you use `pytest` format for setup and teardown

```
# with request.addfinalizer
@pytest.fixture(scope='class', autouse=True)
def setup_and_teardown(self, request):
    def teardown():
        print('teardown')

    request.addfinalizer(teardown)

    print('setup')
    yield

# without request.addfinalizer
@pytest.fixture(scope='class', autouse=True)
def setup_and_teardown(self):
    print('setup')
    yield
    print('teardown')

def test_demo(self):
    print('test')
```

Output

```
setup
PASSED                             [100%]test
teardown
```